# Show that the kernel of a bundle morphism with constant rank is a sub-bundle.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, analytic-geometry, vector-bundles

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $\pi: E \to X$ and $\pi ':F \to X$ be smooth vector bundles of $X$. Suppose we have a (smooth) bundle morphism $f:E\to F$ of constant rank. Show that $\pi_{ket(f)}:ker(f) \to X$ is a sub-bundle of $\pi$.

Here $Ker(f)= \cup_{x \in X}ker(f_{x})$ where $f_{x}=f|_{E_{x}}$ the restriction of $f$ to the fibre over $x$.

I'm not sure how to show two things:

(i) That $ker(f)$ is closed in $X$. (I'm using a definition in which sub-manifolds are closed).

(ii) Suppose I have local trivializations $\{(U,h)\}$ of $\pi: E \to X$. Let the rank $E$ be $r$  and suppose that $dim(ker(f_{x}))=s$ for all $x$. We have
$$
h|_{ker(f)\cap\pi^{-1}(U)}:ker(f) \cap \pi^{-1}(U)\to U \times \mathbb{R}^{s}.
$$
I know that I have
$$
h:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U \times \mathbb{R}^{r}.
$$
and that for each $x$ we have $E_{x}\cap ker(f_{x})$ is a vector subspace of dimension $s$ so that if we identify $E_{x}$ with $\mathbb{R}^{r}$ we can choose a basis of $E_{x}$ so that $E_{x}\cap ker(f_{x})$ can be identified with $R^{s}$. I'm just not sure how to find a smooth choice of change of basis that varies with $x$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You typed tangent bundles, but I assume you mean vector bundles. You can use concrete linear algebra (either reduced echelon form or the fact that the kernel is the orthogonal complement of the image of the transpose map) to prove that, assuming constant rank, the kernel varies smoothly with $x$.

Comment: Thank you @Ted Shifrin for pointing out that it should be vector bundles instead of tangent bundles. To follow up on your second point, could I please get you to elaborate more on how to use the reduced echelon form to show continuous dependence of the kernel?

Comment: Review your linear algebra. How do you read off a basis for the kernel from the reduced echelon form? I do not know what terminology you learned this material with.

Comment: Where I’m stuck at is not being able to see how the process of putting a matrix in the reduced echelon form varies continuously with x.